# How do C++ compilers handle malloc failures during new operator?

Tags: c++, compilation, malloc, heap-memory

C++ compilers implement `new Obj` as a wrapper to `malloc(sizeof(Obj))`.  But malloc can fail! What code do C++ compilers insert to handle the failures, and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ standard says about the behaviour:

> [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]
>
> An allocation function that has a non-throwing exception specification ([except.spec]) indicates failure by returning a null pointer value.
> Any other allocation function never returns a null pointer value and indicates failure only by throwing an exception ([except.throw]) of a type that would match a handler ([except.handle]) of type std​::​bad_alloc ([bad.alloc]).

In the non-throwing case, there is no handling needed because returning null is exactly how `malloc` signifies failure.

In the throwing case, a language implementation that wraps `malloc` has to check whether the allocation was successful, and throw if it wasn't.

Comment: Is that to state that `new Obj` can return null? I haven't seen code doing `a = newObj; if (!a) {fail()}...`.  It seems people expect `new` not to return if it fails.

Comment: @SRobertJames `Is that to state that new Obj can return null?` No, that will never return null. But `new std::nothrow Obj` may return null.

Comment: @eerorika `new std::nothrow Obj` => `new(std::nothrow) Obj`